# PDF of exponential random variable power N

Tags: probability, random-variables

if we have RV X follow exponential Distrubution

$$f_X(x)=e^{-x}$$

then what is the PDF of

$$
Y=X^N
$$
N natural number

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\mathbb{P}(Y \leq y ) = \mathbb{P}(X \leq y^{1/N} ) = 1 - \exp\left(-y^{1/N}\right)$$
$$f_Y(y) = \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}y}\mathbb{P}(Y \leq y ) = \frac{1}{N}y^{-(1-1/N)}\exp\left(-y^{1/N}\right)$$

Comment: ok i hop it will be helpful